# Is it possible to specify the outgoing network interface to use for a PHP SoapClient?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I need to bind a SoapClient to a specific outbound network interface, but I cannot find any documentation on this. Is this even possible? If not, what are some possible workarounds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass a stream context to your soapclient constructor that has a bindto options set:

```
$opts = array(
    'socket' => array(
        'bindto' => '192.168.0.100:0',
     ),
);

$ctx = stream_context_create($opts);

$client = new SoapClient('the.wsdl', array('stream_context' => $ctx));
```