# API request from Specific IP

Tags: php, api, ip

I'm using Ultimate Hosting package of GoDaddy. The account has a static IP and SSL installed. Now when I'm trying to use an API which needs static IP. But scripts are sending requests from random IPs. Please suggest me an way.

My Script

```php
    $soap_exception_occured = false;
    
    $wsdl_path = 'http://vrapi.sslwireless.com/?wsdl';
    
    $response = '';
    
    ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', '0'); // disabling WSDL cache
    
    try {
        $client = new SoapClient($wsdl_path);
        }
        
    catch(SoapFault $exception) {
        $soap_exception_occured = true;
        $response .= '\nError occoured when connecting to the SMS SOAP Server!';
        $response .= '\nSoap Exception: '.$exception;
        }
```

I'm using SOAP. Can IP binding help me ?

Comment: This sounds like a question more suited to GoDaddy's technical support.

Comment: Thanks Quentin, anyway GoDaddy won't provide full fixed IP to send request. But I heard it's possible to bind IP for requesting to SOAP. Can that help me?
I found a tuto [here][1], should that be a solution for me?

[1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444359/is-it-possible-to-specify-the-outgoing-network-interface-to-use-for-a-php-soapcl?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know what happend

```
$soap_exception_occured = false;
$ipandport = array(
    'socket' => array(
        'bindto' => 'xx.xx.xx.xx:port',
     ),
);
$setip  = stream_context_create(ipandport);

$wsdl_path = 'http://vrapi.sslwireless.com/?wsdl';

$response = '';

ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', '0'); // disabling WSDL cache

try {
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl_path, array('stream_context' => $setip));
    }

catch(SoapFault $exception) {
    $soap_exception_occured = true;
    $response .= '\nError occoured when connecting to the SMS SOAP Server!';
    $response .= '\nSoap Exception: '.$exception;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using curl of php to connect to that API, you should bind each request to your IP:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, $myIP);
```

To bind CURL to a different outgoing network interface or a different IP address, all that is needed is to set the CURLOPT_INTERFACE to the appropriate value before executing the CURL request:

Comment: Thanks Armand, I'm using SOAP, I forgot to mention. Would this can help me?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444359/is-it-possible-to-specify-the-outgoing-network-interface-to-use-for-a-php-soapcl?rq=1

Comment: I believe that should be the solution for you!

Comment: Sorry Tanmoy that it did not work. 
Probably a good solving poing might be using the PHP Soap implementations: http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

Answer (score 0):

This thread will be a not complete without file_get_contents:

```
$opts = array(
    'socket' => array(
        'bindto' => 'xx.xx.xx.xx:0',
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

echo file_get_contents('http://www.example.com', false, $context);
```